# Haskell list recursion - why does one work and not the other?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, primes

Anyone familiar with Haskell will have likely seen this implementation of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

The way I understand this is as follows:

- Haskell's lazy evaluation allows for this infinite recursion with no issues
- The way Haskell constructs lists (pairing the first element with the rest of the list) means the zipWith is evaluated to obtain the next element when needed
- When `fibs` is referenced in the zipWith parameters, it takes the list as it currently exists without the new element being evaluated

With that knowledge, why does this loop infinitely rather than generate a list of primes?

```
main = print $ take 10 primes

dividesNone x ys = not $ any ((==0) . (x `mod`)) ys

primes = 2:[x | x <- [2..], x `dividesNone` primes]
```

I've tried similar implementations using `dropWhile` and `find` but the same thing happens. I've settled on this one as the one I most think "should" work. I'm sure there is some way to make this work the way I want - but even if I knew what that way was, I wouldn't understand why this doesn't. **What is the difference between these two examples that causes one to work and one to loop infinitely?**

Comment: You do not need to test for the prime numbers that are beyond the square root of the candidate number; this is infinitely too expensive. Try with this change: `dividesNone x ys = not $ any  ((==0) . (x `mod`))  (takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= x) ys)`

Comment: @jpmarinier Thank you for pointing that out, but I'm aware. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When fibs is referenced in the zipWith parameters, it takes the list as it currently exists without the new element being evaluated.

It holds a reference to the list that is not entirely evaluated yet. But if it had to access the third element before that was evaluated, it would get stuck in an infinite loop. It thus initially looks like:

```
            ╭─────────────────────────────────╮
            │          ╭────────────────────╮ │
            ▽          ▽                    │ │
        ┌───┼───╮  ┌───┼───╮  ┌───────────╮ │ │
fibs ─▷ │ o │ o───▷│ o │ o───▷│  zipWith  │ │ │
        └─│─┴───╯  └─│─┴───╯  ├───┬───┬───┤ │ │
          ▽          ▽        │ o │ o │ o───╯ │
          0          1        └─│─┴─│─┴───╯   │
                                ▽   ╰─────────╯
                               (+)
```

and the `zipWith` will each time evaluate an item, and then the references will move to the next node, and that node is always evaluated already, or at least sufficient to not get into an infinite loop, so the next step, it looks like:

```
                       ╭─────────────────────────────────╮
                       │          ╭────────────────────╮ │
                       ▽          ▽                    │ │
        ┌───┬───╮  ┌───┼───╮  ┌───┼───╮  ┌───────────╮ │ │
fibs ─▷ │ o │ o───▷│ o │ o───▷│ o │ o───▷│  zipWith  │ │ │
        └─│─┴───╯  └─│─┴───╯  └─│─┴───╯  ├───┬───┬───┤ │ │
          ▽          ▽          │        │ o │ o │ o───╯ │
          0          1          ▽        └─│─┴─│─┴───╯   │
          △          △        ┌───────╮    ▽   ╰─────────╯
          │          │        │  (+)  │   (+)
          │          │        ├───┬───┤
          ╰──────────│──────────o │ o │
                     │        └───┴─│─╯
                     ╰──────────────╯
```

That is also what happens with your `primes`. The `dividesNone` will for example look for `3`, and thus walk to the end of the thus far evaluated `primes` list. But since `3` is not dividable by `2`, it will enumerate further, and thus walk into an unevaluated node. It will thus start evaluating the third item of the `primes` list (in order to evaluate the third element of the `prime` list), but that will again require to generate the third item, and thus gets stuck in an infinite loop.

It thus does *not* get a "copy" of the list that stops where it still has to evaluate. The list simply points to a node that still needs to be evaluated, triggering the interpreter to evaluate it, and thus gets it stuck into an infinite loop.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying the difference is that the fibs list builds itself *as part of* that evaluation, while the list comprehension is stuck because it has to test against the entire list *before* calculating the next element?

Comment: @scatter: yes. From the moment it has to evaluate against something that is at that point unevaluated, then there is a problem.

Comment: Are you using a tool to create these unicode diagrams?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: yes, `ascii-art-to-unicode`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ascii-art-to-unicode although it requires some (minimal) post-processing.

Answer (score 4):

From a [denotational](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) perspective, it's because `2:⊥` is a fixed point of the equation that defines `primes`.

The semantics of Haskell say that the meaning of a recursive definition is the *least fixed point* of the equation -- we should find the *least defined* value that satisfies the equation.  Our equation is:

```
primes = 2:[x | x <- [2..], x `dividesNone` primes]
```

Notice that `` 3 `dividesNone` (2:⊥) `` gives `⊥`.  The check against `2` fails, then we ask if `3` divides any of the elements of the list `⊥`, a list about which there is no information, so we have no information about that answer.

If we fill in `2:⊥` for `primes`:

```
2:⊥ = 2 : [x | x <- [2..], x `dividesNone` 2:⊥]  -- 2 fails the filter
    = 2 : [x | x <- [3..], x `dividesNone` 2:⊥]
    = 2 : [x | x <- [3..], ⊥]
    = 2:⊥
```

It satisfies the equation.  And the only things less defined than `2:⊥` are  `⊥` and `⊥:⊥`, which do not satisfy the equation:

```
⊥   /= 2:[x | x <- [2..], x `dividesNone` ⊥]   = 2:⊥
⊥:⊥ /= 2:[x | x <- [2..], x `dividesNone` ⊥:⊥] = 2:⊥
```

So `2:⊥` is the least fixed point.  That is, we will output two and then infinite loop.

In practice I use both the denotational and operational perspectives to reason about my code.  Thinking about laziness operationally can get really complicated really quickly, so it's nice to have another tool in your belt.

Comment: I think I'm a little early in my FP journey to fully grasp this answer, but being exposed to concepts like this is going to be helpful. I look forward to adding this tool to my belt in the near future!